# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This question has been asked before but none of the solutions have worked. I am using:

- OS X 11.0.1
- PHP 7.4.9
- mySQL 8.0.20
- Laravel Framework 8.18.1

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to run some code to connect to the DB.

I am able to connect to the database via Adminer.php and my SQL client, but when trying to access the database, I get:

> *Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select `name` from `products` where `id` = 4 limit 1)*

My env  file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=storify
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=rootroot
```

My guess is that it cannot connect to the local DB instance. I have tried setting the host to 127.0.0.1:3306. I have also tried to edit the database.php to troubleshoot further but the message persists:

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'rootroot',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
```

I also run this command every time I make a change:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

If I change the host to something obviously incorrect, I still get the same error, so Laravel is definitely not finding the host for some weird reason.

My hosts file only contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost.local
```

phpAdmin screen:

[phpMyAdmin Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoHeA.jpg)

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The entry for `'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306') ` is missing from the config snippet posted in your question - do you have this entry in the config?

Comment: You likely don't have a database running on server `127.0.0.1`. MySQL does not use networking in its default configuration. Change the host to `localhost` and ensure your socket is set to point to the correct location.

Comment: Sensitive info like `username`, `password`, `host` etc should not be hard coded in the config file as they are not excluded from the vcs. Define such info in `.env` file which is excluded from version control and use `env()` helper in config file

Comment: Yes, don't touch the database config file at all. Use the env file to change your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help...everything in my configuration was fine. After doing a million things, this command made everything work fine:

php artisan config:clear